# Prove f is not Riemann-Stieltjes integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

f:[a,b]$\to \mathbb{R}$. If c$\in$(a,b) and f is not continuous at c,show that there exists an increasing function g:[a,b]$\to \mathbb{R}$ such that f is not Riemann-Stieltjes integrable on [a,b] with respect to g.

I cant figure out a way to solve this problem.Can anyone tell me how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

For all we know, $f$ is continuous everywhere but at $c$ and if $\alpha(x)$ (where $\alpha(x)$ is the monotonically increasing function that we integrate $f$ with respect to) is continuous at every discontinuity of $f$ (for $f$ with finitely many discontinuities) then $f\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$. To avoid this, we must pick an $\alpha$ that is discontinuous at $c$. Then show that for some nice $\alpha(x)$, if $f\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ then $f$ is continuous at c.

This $\alpha(x)$ should work well:

> $\alpha(x)=\left\{  \begin{array}{lr} 0 &  x<c\\ \frac{1}{2} &  x=c\\ 1 & x>c \end{array} \right.$

Comment: Consider the given function as the increasing function and prove if f is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable then f is continuous at c?

Comment: Yes - $\alpha(x)$ is the function that we integrate $f$ with respect to.

Comment: It only states that f is not continuous at c but not about all the other points.So i thought it may or may not be continuous at all the other points.I couldnt understand the problem.Thanks ill try this approach and see

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "if $f\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ then $f$ is continuous at $c$." I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: ''For all we know, ff is continuous everywhere but at c and if α(x)... .'' My problem is that we dont know about the other points ,Q only states that f is  not continuous at c  ?

Comment: The argument I hinted at does not depend on the continuity of c elsewhere. All I meant was that a priori $f$ could be very nice away from $c$ so that in this "worst-case" scenario where the function is as "hard" as possible to make unintegrable, we definitely need to make $\alpha$ discontinuous at $c$ because otherwise the theorem I mentioned above would give integrability.

Comment: I have to suppose that f is RS integrable with respect to your function alpha and show that f is continuous at c.Which is a contradiction. I tried to do it but i cant proceed in order to show that f is continuous at c . Can you help?